# Why does XslCompiledTransform add META tag to HTML output?

Tags: .net, xslt

I use this code to transform XML to HTML using XSLT template:

```
string uri = Server.MapPath("~/template.xslt");
XslCompiledTransform xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
xsl.Load(uri);
XDocument xml = new XDocument(new XElement("Root"));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
XmlReader reader = xml.CreateReader();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, xsl.OutputSettings);
xsl.Transform(reader, writer);
writer.Close();
```

My template looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"  />
<xsl:template match="Root">
    <html>
       <head>...
```

Output is correct however it contains META tag. How to disable transform so it would not generate META tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XSLT 1.0 specification for output method="html" (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-HTML-Output-Method) mandates that a meta element is output if there is a head section in the result tree:

> If there is a HEAD element, then the
>   html output method should add a META
>   element immediately after the
>   start-tag of the HEAD element
>   specifying the character encoding
>   actually used.

So XslCompiledTransform does what an XSLT processor should do. If you don't want the meta element you will need to explain in more detail what kind of output you want exactly or why the meta is a problem if you want html output. You could of course use output method="xml", that way you won't get the meta element but I am not sure the serialization result that way will be what you want for stuff like 'br' element nodes.

Comment: +1 Faster answer. It's posible to use an `xml` serialization method for ouput XHTML document that follows [HTML Compatibility Guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines)

Comment: Meta is a problem because in html output has no end tag. I suppose XHTML would have tag properly closed.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**:

**Use**:

```
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
```

This eliminates any added HTML tags susch as `<meta>`.

At the same time, you may have difficulties achieving the exact wanted lexical representation of some elements.

**In XSLT 2.0 one can use**:

```
<xsl:output method="xhtml"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It also depends upon the doctype you insert from your output tag.  Using XHTML, for example, omits the META tag.

```
   <xsl:output method="html"
               doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
               doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the html output without add a MATE tag just add a xml namespace in html tag 
like this

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```