# XML Transformation with XSL error - please really need answer

Tags: xml, xslt

I've tried transforming my XML to HTML

It already says transformation completed, but the new document generated says

Ln 6 Col 6 - The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".
1 Error

I've tried adding  closing tag, then it just keeps showing another error...

Here's the code

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="announcement.xsl" ?>-->

<announcement>

    <content>
        <a_num>Announcement</a_num>
        <a_date>Friday, November 7th 2014</a_date>
        <a_subject>Announcement Page</a_subject>
        <a_details>
            We are pleased to announce of Harbour Tennis CupTournament is open to all members of Harbour Island Tennis Club and preliminary rounds will need to be played in the weeks leading up to Finals Day on Saturday 21st November.

            Players can enter more than one age group, ie their own and one age group above. We have added an additional Girls Hardball group for ages 12 through 18, but feel free to enter mixed groups too. Entry is RM20 per event and all juniors are encouraged to enter.

            Consolation rounds will be played for those knocked out in the first round so everyone is guaranteed at least 2 matches.

            Finals Day is a great day of tennis with senior and junior matches being played. There will be a BBQ and the bar will be open so make a note in your diary and come along with family and friends.

            The deadline for entries is 10th May.

            Any questions, please feel free to contact me.

            Many thanks,
            Ahmad Naqib
        </a_details>
    </content>

    <content>
        <a_num>Announcement 2</a_num>
        <a_date>October 1st, 2014</a_date>
        <a_subject>Court Maintenance</a_subject>
        <a_details>
            Hi Harbour Tennis Players!

            We are pleased to announce that our maintenance work is complete and all tennis facilities are now available to our section members.
            On that subject, we would like to remind all tennis members of the importance of having tennis section membership and having proper tennis cards in order to use the facilities. As a section we are both partially and fully funding the replacement and maintenance of the infrastructure (i.e. courts) and tennis equipment (nets, lights etc). For this reason non-section members are not allowed to use the tennis courts or receive tennis coaching. For further information, please contact Reza at 018 337-5754 or reza@harbourtennis.com

        </a_details>
    </content>

    <content>
        <a_num>Announcement 3</a_num>
        <a_date>October 17th, 2014</a_date>
        <a_subject>How to reserve court</a_subject>
        <a_details>
            1. Mon-Thurs (4-10pm) - courts are booked via a booking sheet at our tennis court. You can also phone or email our reception to reserve a court. Each afternoon the booking sheet is posted on the tennis notice board, for members to refer to.

            2. Fri – Sun – courts are booked via “walk-in” booking. In order to make a “Walk-in” booking you have to have a tennis section membership card. You make a walk-in booking using the green board on the wall near to the tennis shop. To make one of these bookings a valid booking requires members to fully understand the rules. Common rules to be reminded of are: 
                        • you can only make a booking 30mins beforehand
                        • only one member of the same family can book one court during each hour time-slot
                        • members of the same family cannot book a court for 2 consecutive hours
            It should be noted, however, that if you turn up (or you are already playing) and no one has booked the court you want to use (either by phone booking or Walk-In) or it is 5mins after the hour and the court is empty then any member can claim that court as their own until the hour time slot is finished. 
        </a_details>
    </content>

    <content>
        <a_num>Announcement 4</a_num>
        <a_date>November 3rd, 2014</a_date>
        <a_subject>How to reserve court</a_subject>
        <a_details>
        Our popular summer holiday tennis camps will be held on the following dates:

        11th - 15th November
        18th - 23rd November
        26th -29th November
        Morning session 9 a.m. to 12 noon
        Afternoon session 1 p.m. to 4 p.m.

        Lunch will be 12 noon to 1 p.m.

        Members : RM50 per session 
        Non Members : RM65 per session 
        </a_details>
    </content>

</announcement>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
<head>
    <title>Announcement</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
          <div id="header-left">
              <img src="images/logo-test.png"/>
          </div>
        </header>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="borderradiusleft">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Information</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="history.html">About &amp; History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="rules.html">Tennis Rules</a></li>
                        <li><a href="equipments.html">Equipments</a></li>
                        <li><a href="techniques.html">Techniques</a></li>
                        <li><a href="benefits.html">Benefits</a></li>
                        <li><a href="newsevents.html">News &amp; Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tennisclub.html">Tennis Club</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="newsevents.html">Organization Chart</a></li>
                            <li><a href="membership.html">Membership</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="announcement.xml">Announcement</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li class="borderradiusright"><a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <xsl:for-each select="announcement/content">
                  <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px;margin:2px;">
                    <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="a_num"/> - </span>
                    <xsl:value-of select="a_date"/>
                  </div>
                  <div style="margin:20px 0px;font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="a_subject"/></div>
                  <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
                    <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="a_details"/>
                    </p>
                  </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div id="footer-left">
                <div class="block">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>    
                        <li><a href="history.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="newsevents.html">News &amp; Events</a></li>                           
                        <li><a href="cluborganization.html">Club Organization Chart</a></li>          
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="block">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="equipments.html">Equipments</a></li>
                      <li><a href="benefits.html">Benefits</a></li>
                        <li><a href="techniques.html">Techniques</a></li>
                        <li><a href="riles.html">Rules of Tennis</a></li>
                        <li><a href="equipments.html">Image Map</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="block">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="tennisclub.html">Tennis Club</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cluborganization.html">Organization Chart</a></li>
                        <li><a href="membership/form.html">Membership</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact_us.html">Announcement</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer-right">
                <h4>Get in touch with us</h4>
                <img src="images/logo-test.png" width="90"/>
                <p>
                    <strong>Harbour Island Tennis Centre</strong><br/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If hard to see can be downloaded here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8p5mnc8e9inmxoj/Announcement.zip?dl=0

I would really really appreciate your help..

Thank you very much

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippet in the question. Nobody here is going to download some random zip file.

Comment: Right.. sorry. I've just added the code in the post.

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced using the code you have posted: http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKvX

Comment: @michael.hor257k I know.. that's why I'm asking for help.. cause I don't know what I did wrong..

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the current error that you're getting.

Comment: @matthias_h hello, I've already put the error in my post. When transformation completed, it shows : Ln 6 Col 6 - The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "". 1 Error

Comment: I thought that would already be fixed by adding the closing link-tag; I mean the "another error" in the sentence "I've tried adding closing tag, then it just keeps showing another error."

Comment: @matthias_h oh sorry. after I closed the link. It shows 2 errors 


Ln 1 Col 7 - cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'html'.
Ln 6 Col 6 - The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".

Comment: There is no <meta> element in your code. Are you sure you have provided the correct documents?

Comment: @michael.hor257k The `<meta>` element is added automatically as visible in the output of your xsltransform-example. For explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408725/why-does-xslcompiledtransform-add-meta-tag-to-html-output#answer-4409047  answer by Martin Honnen

Comment: @matthias_h Ah, of course. I would have seen this, if I hadn't already changed my code to the suggested one.

Comment: @RionPrawira I have rolled back your edit. Please don't delete your question after it has been answered - it might help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, the problem is with your browser not accepting an unclosed `link` element. Try adding the following element to the top level of your stylesheet (outside of any template):

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
```

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you very much @michael.hor257k if the assignment is asking for the page to be an output of XSLT transformation. From home page, Do I link the hyperlink to announcement.xml file or the announcement.html which I've generated from this transformation?

Comment: @RionPrawira Just curious: which browser is giving you the error?

Comment: it's Firefox.. and I'm having another issue with my JS calculation on Firefox as well... please check it out if you have time --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958392/javascript-calculation-only-works-on-chrome-but-not-firefox-other-browser

Comment: @RionPrawira That's strange, because I can open both the source and the result in FF with no problems whatsoever.